# Mobile device recognised by ADB or by Chrome dev tools but not by both

Tags: android-studio, google-chrome-devtools, adb

My android device is recognized by ADB but not by Chrome development tools. If I kill the ADB server, then the device is recognized by Chrome dev tools.

I cannot use Chrome for remote debugging.

ADB was installed through Android Studio

*My Mac environment:*

```
ADB: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 0.0.1-4500957
Installed as /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
Chrome: Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

By trying `adb kill-server` the device is visible in Chrome
Whenever I execute `adb start-server`, and then adb devices the result is:

```
List of devices attached
ECPBBCB6C3105088    device
```

I'm struggling with this for some time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**That can happen only if two software with two `adb.exe` are working.**

I first got the problem, When I tried using KingoROOT Software which had it's own ADB Tools in its installation path and, I was trying to launch ADB from SDK path.

**Only, one instance of ADB will work.**

If you try to use the `adb.exe` which is used by Chrome Dev Tools, it will work.

What you can try is, if you're on Windows, first open Chrome Dev Tools then, open *task manager*, check **Show Processes For All Users**, then find the `adb.exe` started by Chrome Dev Tools. Give a right-click and goto **Open File Location**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great clue thank you. I'm on Mac. I will pursue it and return to post my results.

Comment: I'll wait for your reply. Good luck!

Comment: Not successfull on solving the problem, but found an alternative. I was building my through command line, not Android Studio. Lately I was having problems with the build process (gradle from brew) and also with ADB. I found out that using Android Studio everything was smoother, including the deployment to my device, allowing for Chrome debugging. Now I have a bit weired envrionment because I'm still compiling my app through command line and build through android Studio. But it solved my problems.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your support and for the guiding. In a way, your input helped me to find a solution

Comment: Additional investigations for those who have this problem:

Comment: For those with similar problem: What worked for me: First ensure device is visible on Chrome. I've executed sudo lsof -i | grep 5037 and killed all processes (including Chrome). After, relaunch Chrome and on my device, enable/disable device , I managed to make my device visible on Chrome. Next, making device visible to Android Studio. Launch Android Studio, build my project finish and run it. Then cames the popup starting ADB. Again, with enable/disable my device I managed to make it visible to AS. Now  just run to deploy your app to the device